# Linux (CentOS): Confirm that a disk device is a USB pen drive without logs

Tags: linux, centos, hardware, usb-flash-drive

We have a USB pen drive connected to our server. It was connected months ago so we the log of the initial connection have since been rotated out.

I know you could obtain the make and model of a device (e.g., `/dev/sdc`) from the `/var/log/messages` log messages. However, how would we be able to obtain that without access to the logs?

Comment: "was", as in, it's no longer connected, or "was" as in connected months ago and still plugged in?

Comment: Connected long ago. Sorry. Edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `lsusb` command may be helpful (assuming the device is still connected).

Update: The original question asked for the make/model which is not `/dev/sdc` that confused me (lsusb should have shown the make/model).  You could use the `sg_scan` and `sg_map` commands:

```
# sg_map
/dev/sg0   /dev/sda
/dev/sg1   /dev/scd0
/dev/sg3   /dev/sdc
```

Now we know that `/dev/sdc` maps to `/dev/sg3` use

```
# sg_scan -i
...
/dev/sg3: scsi10 channel=0 id=0 lun=0
   Verbatim STORE N GO PMAP [rmb=1 cmdq=0 pqual=0 pdev=0x0]
```

You will need the `sg3_utils` rpm installed for access to the sg utils.

Finally, for joechip, the `udisks --dump` command can show you the link between usb/scsi. Look for `native-path`.

```
native-path:   /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/host10/target10:0:0:/block
```

and `device`:

```
device: 8,32
```

Not pleasant to look at but there if you need it.

Comment: How would I tie that to a disk device though?

Comment: Yes, lsusb is useful but still AFAIK obtaining the kernel-name associated to each usb device is not a well-defined process (at least not using command-line utilities and /proc/sys files). For HID devices there is a file called "dev" which tells the major:minor device numbers of the kernel name. But for USB storage devices there doesn't seem to be such thing. Anybody please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If it's still plugged in, [dmidecode](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dmidecode) may give you the info, or you may find something buried in /proc.  If you mean was plugged in months ago and has since been removed, then logs are probably your only choice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a complete answer, but if you don't have access to the log files you might still be able to run dmesg and identify the /dev/sd* device that has been associated to the usb-storage device upon plugging it. Unless such information has been flushed from dmesg by now, of course.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `dmidecode` as suggested previously...

```
$ cat /proc/bus/usb/devices
# lshw
```